# my redux is not working the way i wrote it down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-state-management

Lately, I have been trying to use Redux but I get no error and no dev tool error and my page are blank.

So I started my code with the basic Redux boilerplate. I created a userslice, a store and then I provided the store as a wrapper for the `<app/>`.

Yet after spending hours I can't get to fix the code. Code should just give me back the **username** inside a **div** using `useselector` hook that initialized but it does not seem to work.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  const username = useSelector(state => state.username)
  return (
    <div className="App">
    
   {username}

     
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

userSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name:'user'
,
initialState:{
    username:'Tony stark',
    post:'',

},

reducers:{
    updatePost:(state,action)=>{
        state.username = action.payload;

    }
}})

export const { updatePost} = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducers;
```

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import userSlice from '../redux/userSlice'
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    
    user: userSlice,
  },
});
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '../src/redux/store'
import App from './App';

import './index.css';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's in the `userSlice` you'll need to get it from the `user` property of the Redux root state, like so:

`const username = useSelector(state => state.user.username)`

Your initial Redux state (annotated) should look like this:

```
{ // <-- state
  user: { // <-- state.user
    username: 'Tony stark', // <-- state.user.username
    post: '' // <-- state.user.post
  }
}
```